# Textview aarangement in android

Tags: android, textview

[image: This is what it is]
[image: This is what i want]

Can this be possible ?

Note the Textview text are dynamically set.

Only the Label are static.

Comment: What is the concrete problem? I didn't get it.

Comment: He wants a TextView, then an EditText close to it which expands even under the TextView.

Comment: will the second line text of textview which is containing data can come under textview(label medium text)?

Comment: Short answer: **NO**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Not necessary edittext .. i am ok with both textviews

Comment: Please understand that Views have a "rectangular" shape. So it will stay parallel.

Comment: Try to use LinearLayout with weights and weightsum

Comment: What is possible is to **draw** on the canvas, by using `drawText()`. OR... why 2 TextViews? You can set different spans in the same TextView (i.e.: different text colors or bold/normal weight).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein You mean even the static label will come dynamically with data while binding.

Comment: yes you can do it with single textview using the html formater class so you can set heading highlighted and other is normal text

Comment: Here are the tags supported by `Html.fromHtml`: https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html